# Google Drive API after google sign - Vue.Js

Tags: vue.js, google-api, vue-component, drive

I already did the google sign-in with the plugin `vue-google-auth` (more info in: https://github.com/simmatrix/vue-google-auth) returning one object called `GoogleUserS`.
Now i want to store in that google account's drive some config files of the website. 
How can i do that?

Edit: some user sign in in my site and choose some channels it creates a file called channels.txt and i want to store that in user's google drive account (assuming that user has a google account and already sign in with that google account in my site)

Comment: Hi ! Could you please provide some piece of code you've already written ? And where are you stuck into ?

Comment: Hi @toshiro92 , i didnt write nothing for google drive api because i dont find nothing for vue.js. I already tried google drive picker but this shows everything on user google drive and i dont want that. I want to store files in google drive instead of local storage or something like this.